# How can I create a health bar in the compiler relative to the max health and length of the bar?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a way to represent any number of health with `System.out.print("#")` 100 times in a line to make a health bar in the compiler.

The damage taken is represented by "-" and the "|" just represents the start and end of the bar.

What I have here works only if the health is equal to 100, otherwise the health bar will grow or just take damage relative to 100 (the number of printed hashtags).

What are some ideas on how I can tackle this?

I've already tried making a double called compression equal to 100 over the health and using this to subtract or add certain numbers of "#," but health is constantly changing (due to taken damage) and this doesn't work.

```
    health = health - damage;
    String nameC = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < equaliser.length; i++) {                            
            System.out.print(equaliser[i]);
    }
    System.out.print(nameC + ": |");
    for (int i = 0; i < health; i++) {
        System.out.print("#");
        }
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100-health; i++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    
    if (health < 100) {
        System.out.print("|");
    }
    System.out.print(health);
    System.out.println();        //Return health so that the combat method in main recognises
    return health;               //When a match is over. 
}
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. What do you mean with `otherwise the health bar will grow or just take damage relative to 100 (the number of printed hashtags).` and `but health is constantly changing (due to taken damage) and this doesn't work.`?  What is the expected output for a certain value and what is the wrong output your get?

Comment: I mean the actual length of the bar will exceed 100 if the health is larger than 100 and that if it is less than 100, it will just look as if the character has taken damage. I want the health bar to never exceed 100 hashtags and always start at 100 hashtags even if the health begins above or below 100. 
Health would always update to a new number at the beginning of the code (health = health - damage) and obviously this stops health from being constant so I couldn't use this as a viable approach
Does that clarify at all? Sorry for the tags, I have only been programming for about 3 months

Comment: You could think of health (relative to maxHealth) as a percentage. ``100.0 * (double)health / maxHealth`` should be s number between 0 and 100. Use Math.floor to convert it to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the display bar to be 100 characters long but the `health` value itself may not be 100.  So the health bar is showing the percentage of health available.

So your inputs are `maxHealth` and `health`.  I'm also making `barSize` a parameter here - you would pass 100 since that is the desired size, but you may want to provide a mini-bar in some displays.

```
private String toHealthBar(int health, int maxHealth, int barSize) {
  StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder("|");
  double percentage = ((double)health)/maxHealth;
  int numHearts = (int)(percentage * barSize);
  for (int ii = 0 ; ii < numHearts ; ++ii) {
    bar.append("#");
  }
  for (int ii = numHearts ; ii < barSize ; ++ii) {
    bar.append("-");
  }
  return bar.append("|").toString();
}
```

Consider modeling health as its own class.  This will allow you to implement bounds checking and the like cleanly.  The above method can then be added to that class and the parameters reduced to just the `barSize`.

Comment: For someone with very little coding expierence, this one works and makes the most sense to me. Thanks a lot vsfDawg!

Answer (score 0):

The keeping and processing of data should always be kept separate from the output. A `Health` class that processes inputs such as damage or healing can ensure that the minimum and maximum values are not exceeded. Last but not least, a render method can output the data in the desired form.

**Edit:**
I changed the `Health` class from `int` to `double` so that the class can process floating point values. The `render` method now also accepts a length specification.

An example:

```
public class Health {
    private double maxHealth = 100;
    private double curHealth = maxHealth;

    public void takeDamage(double damage){
        if(damage < 0) damage = 0;
        curHealth -= damage;
        if(curHealth < 0) curHealth = 0;
    }

    public void getHeal(double heal){
        if(heal < 0) heal = 0;
        curHealth += heal;
        if(curHealth > maxHealth) curHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public String render(){
        return render(100);
    }

    public String render(int barLength){
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        int curChars = (int)Math.ceil(curHealth / maxHealth * barLength);

        sb.append("#".repeat(curChars));
        sb.append("-".repeat(barLength - curChars));

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

An additional class to test the `Health` Class helps you to check whether the desired result is achieved.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var health = new Health();
        print(health);
        health.takeDamage(50);
        print(health);
        health.getHeal(10);
        print(health);
        health.takeDamage(59);
        print(health);
        health.takeDamage(1);
        print(health);
    }

    private static void print(Health health){
        System.out.println(health.render());
    }
}
```

There are certainly other, different or even better methods to achieve the desired result. See the whole thing only as an example that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach of a HealthBar class:

```
public class HealthBar {

    private int hearts, maxHearts;
    private double health, maxHealth;

    public HealthBar(int maxHearts, double health) {

        this.maxHearts = maxHearts;
        this.maxHealth = health;
        this.health = health;

        calculateHearts(maxHealth);
    }

    public void setHealth(double health) {

        this.health = health;
        double maxHealth = Math.max(health, this.maxHealth);

        calculateHearts(maxHealth);
    }

    public void setMaxHealth(double maxHealth) {

        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
        calculateHearts(maxHealth);
    }

    public void setMaxHearts(int maxHearts) {

        this.maxHearts = maxHearts;
        calculateHearts(maxHealth);
    }

    private void calculateHearts(double maxHealth) {

        double heartValue = maxHealth / maxHearts;
        this.hearts = (int) Math.ceil(health / heartValue);
    }

    public void print() {

        StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder("|");

        for(int i = 0; i < hearts; i++)
            bar.append("#");

        int damage = Math.max(maxHearts - hearts, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < damage; i++)
            bar.append("-");

        bar.append("|");

        System.out.println(bar);
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
HealthBar healthbar = new HealthBar(20, 10);
healthbar.setHealth(0.2);
healthbar.print();
```

Output(20 possible hearts, max health 10):

```
|#-------------------|
```

Please note that this class uses Math.ceil instead of Math.floor because using Math.floor could lead to confusing behavior. This is why I decided to use 0.2 for health in the example. When using Math.floor the health-bar would display zero hearts left, which indicates that the player has no more health left but in fact, there is still a little bit of health available.

Answer (score 0):

Or just for fun like this:

```
public String HealthBar(double curHealth, double maxHealth, int barLength){
    int curChars = (int)Math.ceil(curHealth / maxHealth * barLength);
    return "|" + "#".repeat(curChars) + "-".repeat(barLength - curChars) + "|";
}
```